# how to remove slashes from json response in laravel

Tags: json, laravel

I use laravel for `API`. I already add stripslash function to remove slashes.

```
$content = stripcslashes($raw["f_content"]);
```

its give me proper result as I want.
but when I send it in `JSON` response it will convert in slashe back here it is `JSON` response.

```
return response()->json($body);
{
        "f_id": 1,
        "f_content": "comment's \"Hi\"",
        "f_rant_id": 14,
        "f_user_id": 1,
        "upvote": 0,
        "downvote": 0,
        "f_image_url": null,
        "f_status": 0,
        "updated_at": {
            "date": "2017-12-11 17:55:22.000000",
            "timezone_type": 3,
            "timezone": "UTC"
        },
        "created_at": {
            "date": "2017-12-11 17:55:22.000000",
            "timezone_type": 3,
            "timezone": "UTC"
        },
        "f_email": "jfkhelp@gmail.com",
        "f_name": "",
        "f_password": null,
        "f_facebook_id": "531515500542146",
        "first_name": "Kyle",
        "last_name": "Wal",
        "party_name": null,
        "evericode": 0,
        "f_last_logintime": "2017-12-11 17:55:22"
}
```

Comment: Try: `str.replace(/\\/g, "");`

Comment: can you give me example for this ????

Comment: Like: `var finalData = str.replace(/\\/g, ""); alert(finalData);` Let me know if this works!

Comment: Thanks bro but it not works for me because its in php

Comment: Then try: `JSON.parse(JSON.parse(json).data));`  Use data or any which you have in `JSON.parse(json).data`!

Comment: The slashes are needed to give a valid JSON and JSON decode should remove them. The slashes are to escape " to say it is part of a string and not used to encapsulate a string. \" will result in " after decoding

Comment: OR you can also try: `echo str_replace('\/','/',json_encode($mydatas));`

Comment: @ParthSureliya Which is works for you? Let me know!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
var finalData = str.replace(/\\/g, ""); 
alert(yourdata);
```

OR

```
json_encode($yourdata, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

OR

```
echo str_replace('\/','/',json_encode($yourdata));
```

OR

You have to decode the `JSON` twice, e.g.

```
var data = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(json).yourdata));
```

Hope any of this will helps you!!